# Bash get size of a list of files extracted with head command

Tags: bash, pipe, size

I have have the following bash command, which gives me 300 random files of a folder.

> ls /directory/ | sort -R | head -n 300

I want to get the total size of the 300 random file like so

> ls /directory/ | sort -R | head -n 300 | du -h

The problem is that 'du' is not executed for these 300 files but for the whole directory where I currently am.

How can I do it?

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: `printf %s\\0 *|grep -zvF \*|head -zn300|sort -zR|du -h --files0-from=-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` and `xargs` like so:

```
find /directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | sort -R | head -n300 | xargs du -sh
```

To print also the total size of all the files that `xargs` fed to `du`, add the `-c` option to `du`, like so: `du -sch`

Comment: You could probably remove the need for du all together if you are using find by using -printf "%k"

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now. But is there a way to also print the total size at the end?

Comment: @PetarYakov Updated the answer.